# How to disable mouse input (PS4 touchpad) in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, ps4

Is there a way to disable touchpad input for PS4 controller in Unity? It is treated as a mouse input. I made sure InputManager does not have any axes with mouse input but touchpad input is still being detected and takes focus away from my menu buttons.
I tried `Input.simulateMouseWithTouches = false;` but does not work.
Is inheriting `StandaloneInputModule` and disabling mouse input the only way?